# Unique VS INSERT IGNORE

Tags: mysql, sql, unique, sql-insert

As you know, `unique` columns only accept non-repetitive values. Now, I saw a keyword named `IGNORE` *(It is used after `INSERT` statement)*.

Well, I read about `INSERT IGNORE` in the documentation and I figured out its job is exactly what `unique` does! So, when should I use `IGNORE` instead of `unique` column? When it is useful?

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` allows you to ignore warning message when violating a unique constraint.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks, it was helpful :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["INSERT IGNORE" vs "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two constructs are complimentary. A `unique` constraint makes sure a column cannot get repetitive values. The `ignore` keyword in an `insert` statement allows the `insert` statement to ignore any errors (such as unique constraint violations) when inserting new rows to a table.

Without the constraint, your insert statement would just create repetitive values in the table. Without the `ignore` keyword, attempting to insert such values would error out instead of just silently doing nothing.

Comment: Well, for hiding the errors when there is a duplicate value, I have to use `IGNORE`. So, I can use both of them, correct? `Unique` to prevent duplicate values, `IGNORE` for hiding errors. Right?